# Bypass scope parameter applied to Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have the following defined:

```
class Category
  has_many :questions, -> { order(weekday: :asc) }
end
```

Is it possible to do a query like the following and to intentionally ignore the lambda above?

```
Category.first.questions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Category.first.questions.unscope(:order)
Category.first.questions.except(:order)
```

See http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/unscope and http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/except.